# Simplification of an algebraic determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

After studying some analytic geometry, I came across this step in a solution, however, I am not how they managed to simplify the determinant in this way.

[image]

When I tried to evaluate this, I got:

$\frac{bc-ad}{2}+\frac{ad-bc}{2b-2d}$, but didn’t see how this got to the desired form. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the first on the first line and the second on the second line. You obtain $$\frac12b\cdot\frac{ad-bc}{d-b}-\frac12\left(-d+d\cdot\frac{ad-bc}{d-b}\right)=\frac d2+(b-d)\frac{ad-bc}{2(d-b)}=\frac{d-ad+bc}{2}$$

Comment: Ah ha! You have illuminated where I made my mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

We obtain

$$\frac12 b\frac{ad-bc}{d-b}-\frac12 d\frac{ad-bc}{d-b}+\frac12d=\frac12 (b-d)\frac{ad-bc}{d-b}+\frac12d=\frac12(bc-ad+d)$$